# TikZ Automata Make An Arrow To Nowhere

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I have the following TikZ code:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,>=stealth',thick]
        \node[state] (1) {$1$};
        \node[state,draw=none] (d1) [left of=1] {};
        \draw [->] (1) to[loop above] node[auto] {} (1);
        \draw [->] (1) to[bend left] node[auto] {} (d1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this image:

[image: TikZ output]

Notice, that I've used a hidden node (d1) above in order to produce the nice arrow going to the left.

The sadness of this is that now I have a big circle-sized empty space.

I'd like to keep the arrow, I'd like the arrow to look the same, but I'd like to get rid of that empty space.

Is there a way to draw the arrow without introducing the invisible node? Or is there a way to crop the figure? What's an elegant way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a `\coordinate` instead of a `\node`:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,>=stealth',thick]
        \node[state] (1) {$1$};
        \coordinate[left of=1] (d1);
        \draw [->] (1) to[loop above] node[auto] {} (1);
        \draw [->] (1) to[bend left] node[auto] {} (d1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To compensate for the arrow tip shortening, you could use

```
   \draw [->,shorten >=0pt] (1) to[bend left] node[auto] {} (d1);
```

in the above code.

Comment: That's a very long arrow going to the left. Is there a way to shorten it (perhaps this was the latter part of your comment, but it doesn't seem to work).

Comment: @Richard: Sure, you can use something like  `\coordinate (d1) at (-1,0);`
 but since you said: "...I'd like the arrow to look the same...", I thought you wanted to keep the original lengths.

Comment: I think your solution leads to an extended arrow, @GonzaloMedina, because the arrow will go to the coordinate which is defined as "left of" d1. This coordinate will be the center of the invisible circular node I'd defined, rather than the edge. Therefore, in your code, the arrow becomes longer.

Answer (score 16):

You could also use the `++` option to specify *go left 2 centimeters from the last position* :

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
        \node[state] (1) {$1$};
        \draw [->] (1) to[loop above] node[auto] {} (1);
        \draw [->] (1) to[bend left] node[auto] {} ++ (-2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A compact code is

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
        \node[state] (1) {$1$};
        \draw [->] (1) edge   [loop above]  ()
                       edge   [bend left]   ++ (-2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The actual problem here is, that the invisible node (`draw=none`) is only used to place the arrow as if there is an actual node. Which works fine but also expands the bounding box.

But there is the special `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment. From the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), 69.3.2 “Graphic Scope Environments”, p. 568f.:

> This environment temporarily interrupts the computation of the
>   bounding box and sets up a new bounding box. At the beginning of the
>   environment the old bounding box is saved and an empty bounding box is
>   installed. After the environment the original bounding box is
>   reinstalled as if nothing has happened.

---

To quote from the question:

> I'd like to keep the arrow,

Check.

> I'd like the arrow to look the same, but I'd like to get rid of that empty space.

Double-check.

> Is there a way to draw the arrow without introducing the invisible node?

Yes, see the other answers.

> Or is there a way to crop the figure?

Yes, there is an additional way: the `\clip` (`\path[clip]`) command/path operation, but that has two disadvantages:

1. It clips only following material.
2. It needs specifying a path that is to be clipped.

> What's an elegant way to solve this problem?

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,>=stealth',thick]
        \node[state] (1) {$1$};
        \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            \node[state,draw=none] (d1) [left of=1] {};
        \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \draw [->] (1) to[loop above] node[auto] {} (1);
        \draw [->] (1) to[bend left]  node[auto] {} (d1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

(Note, that the arrow is shorten by `1pt` and the resulting `.png` has an additional border of `2pt`, hence the arrow does not touch the picture’s margin.)

#### with `draw=none`

[image]

#### without `draw=none`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the case of your MWE, a simple solution uses the `overlay` option:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,>=stealth',thick]
        \node[state] (1) {$1$};
        \node[state,draw=none,overlay] (d1) [left of=1] {};
        \draw [->] (1) to[loop above] node[auto] {} (1);
        \draw [->] (1) to[bend left] node[auto] {} (d1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```