# How to create a Markov chain with an empty node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would create using `tikz` package this Markov chain but I encountered many problems. Who can post the right code to create the follow Markov chain?

[image]

Comment: I can! What are your problems? [What have you tried?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) Where have you failed?

Comment: Usually all the nodes have to be connect among them...but in this case the last node at the right is not connected to anyone!!

Comment: There are lots of automata drawing questions on the site. Start here: [Which package can be used to draw automata?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20784/2693).  If you already have some code, post it (complete document, not a fragment) and then we can help you.

Comment: Without a MWE one can hardly guess what’s wrong. It seems like you have placed a `node` between `2` and `g` but without any content or `draw`. You probably meant to use a `coordinate`.

Comment: A more pertinent related question, perhaps: [TikZ Automata Make an Arrow to Nowhere](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52157/2693).

Comment: Well I will be honest...I have to present a work for tomorrow morning and I have not too much time to spend learning how to build this morkov's chain.if you can help me to post the code I will be very grateful. If it is not possible don't worry...I understand :-)

Comment: go to oDesk....

Comment: To any down voters: we *regularly* get these type of `draw-this-for-me` question on the site; one down vote is enough. Please see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2879/consistent-policy-about-downvoting-and-asking-the-op-to-show-what-they-have-tri for further discussion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## The `positioning` library

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state]                               (0) {0};
\node[state,right=of 0]                    (1) {1};
\node[state,right=of 1]                    (2) {2};
\coordinate[draw=none,right=of 2]          (2-g);
\node[state,right=of {2-g},text depth=0pt] (g) {g};

\draw[
    >=latex,
%   every node/.style={above,midway},% either
    auto=right,                      % or
    loop above/.style={out=75,in=105,loop},
    every loop,
    ]
     (g)   edge[loop above] node {$p_{gg}$}   (g)
           edge             node {$p_{gg-1}$} (2-g)
     (2-g) to               node {$p_{32}$}   (2)
           edge[loop above] node {$p_{22}$}   (2)
     (2)   edge             node {$p_{21}$}   (1)
     (1)   edge[loop above] node {$p_{11}$}   (1)
           edge             node {$p_{10}$}   (0)
     (0)   edge[loop above] node {$p_{00}$}   (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

Replacing the `\coordinate` line with

```
\node[draw=none,right=of 2]           (2-g) {text};
```

you get:

[image]

## The `chains` library

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right]
\node[state, on chain]                 (0) {0};
\node[state, on chain]                 (1) {1};
\node[state, on chain]                 (2) {2};
\node[on chain]                   (2-g) {text};
\node[state, on chain, text depth=0pt] (g) {g};

% The \draw path is like the one above.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks you so much...you are so nice!!!THanks for having dedicate your free time to me!!!

Comment: @Mazzy while you're thanking people,  you might want to check your other questions and accept some more of the answers that helped you.

Comment: is It possible to add some text among the two state 2 and g. I would add ... among those two states. I tried using \text{...} but It gave me error

Comment: @AlanMunn If some questions are not accepted, this means they wasn't right for me...Not all the ans can be useful

Comment: @Mazzy `\text` is, unless otherwise defined, a math-mode macro defined by `amstext` that allows to pick up the text font outside the current math mode. You could place your usual `\node`, just like the others, replacing the `\coordinate` with `\node[right=of 2] (2-g) {<text>};`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel yeah now it worked...thanks again!!!