# Unable to draw this network diagram using tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am at the very beginning stage of Latex drawing using tikz. I am trying to draw a diagram like this
[image]

The MWE that I tried is nowhere near the desired output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{Diagram}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw circle(.5)--(-4,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question it is similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267399/figure-in-tikz-2-state-markov). I have taken the code of the user *@sergej* and I have done some bit changhes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.3cm,->,>=stealth',auto,
  every edge/.append style={thick}]
  \node[state] (1) {$A$};
  \node[state] (2) [right of=1] {$R$};  
  \path (1) edge[loop left]  node{$S_1$} (1)
            edge[bend left]  node{$\scriptstyle S_2$}   (2)
        (2) edge[loop right] node{$S_4$}  (2)
            edge[bend left] node{$\scriptstyle S_3$}     (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, It is really more similar to automata diagrams (DFA, NFA). Thanks, the code is fairly readable and understandable @Sebastiano

Comment: @Bukaida I'm glady to help you. In this site there are same many questions that you can see manually. My best regards.