# Creating a loop after a break using Markov Chain in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create something similar to [image: this figure] using [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89662/how-to-create-a-markov-chain-with-an-empty-node). I modified the source code and this is what I have

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going left,node distance=2cm]   
\node[state, on chain]                 (N+1) {N+1};
\node[state, on chain]                 (N) {N};
\node[on chain]                   (g) {...};
\node[state, on chain]                 (2) {2};
\node[state, on chain]                 (1) {1};
\node[state, on chain]                 (0) {0};
\draw[
    >=latex,
%   every node/.style={above,midway},% either
    auto=right,                      % or
    loop above/.style={out=75,in=105,loop},
    every loop,
    ]
     (0)   edge[loop above] node {$p_{0,0}$}   (0)
           edge             node {$p_{0,1}$} (1)
     (1)   edge[loop above] node {$p_{1,1}$}   (1)
     (1)   edge             node {$p_{1,2}$}   (2)
     (2)   edge[loop above] node {$p_{2,2}$}   (2)
           edge             node {$p_{2,3}$}   (g)
     (g)  edge[] node {$p_{N-1,N}$}   (N);
     (N)   edge[loop above] node {$p_{N,N}$}   (N)
     edge             node {$p_{N,N+1}$}   (N+1)
     (N)   edge[bend left] node {$p_{N,N}$}   (0)
     (N+1)   edge[loop above] node {$p_{N+1,N+1}$}   (N)         
     (N+1)   edge[bend left] node {$p_{N+1,N+1}$}   (0)
        % The \draw path is like the one above.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I seem not to get it right. Where did I get this wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there. You only misplaced the semicolon and confused a label.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going left,node distance=2cm]   
\node[state, on chain]                 (N+1) {$N+1$};
\node[state, on chain]                 (N) {$N$};
\node[on chain]                   (g) {$\cdots$};
\node[state, on chain]                 (2) {$2$};
\node[state, on chain]                 (1) {$1$};
\node[state, on chain]                 (0) {$0$};
\draw[
    >=latex,
%   every node/.style={above,midway},% either
    auto=right,                      % or
    loop above/.style={out=75,in=105,loop},
    every loop,
    ]
     (0)   edge[loop above] node {$p_{0,0}$}   (0)
           edge             node {$p_{0,1}$} (1)
     (1)   edge[loop above] node {$p_{1,1}$}   (1)
     (1)   edge             node {$p_{1,2}$}   (2)
     (2)   edge[loop above] node {$p_{2,2}$}   (2)
           edge             node {$p_{2,3}$}   (g)
     (g)  edge[] node {$p_{N-1,N}$}   (N)
     (N)   edge[loop above] node {$p_{N,N}$}   (N)
     edge             node {$p_{N,N+1}$}   (N+1)
      (N)   edge[bend left] node[below] {$p_{N,N}$}   (0)
     (N+1)   edge[loop above] node {$p_{N+1,N+1}$}   (N)
      (N+1)   edge[bend left] node[below] {$p_{N+1,N+1}$}   (1);
%         % The \draw path is like the one above.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]